# How to reuse an CABasicAnimation when not removed after completion?

Tags: iphone, core-animation

Lots of people are talking about keeping an CABasicAnimation object around after it has been used.

So by setting

> removedOnCompletion = NO

the animation object keeps attached to the layer when the animation is complete. How would I re-launch this animation again without creating a new CABasicAnimation?

What's the point of keeping this object around? The only benefit I know is that we can set removedOnCompletion = NO and set kCAFillModeForwards so that Core Animation does not revert the visual representation back to the model values in the CALayer.

But how to re-use the animation, like everyone is talking about?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this:

1. Add the animation with a key using  [`[layer addAnimation:myAnimation forKey:@"myKey"]`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/quartzcore/calayer/1410848-addanimation?language=objc)
2. To get a reference to it later, call [`[layer animationForKey:@"myKey"]`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/quartzcore/calayer/1410808-animationforkey?language=objc)
3. Read [this note from Apple](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/qa/qa1673/_index.html) which explains how to pause and resume (restart) animations.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me but I am sure someone will tell me the value is already stored in a key..

When I created a layer and assigned an animation to it I set the animation to a keyed value associated with the layer.

in this example layersCurrentAnimation is the CABasicAnimation and myAnimatedLayer is a CALayer.

```
[myAnimatedLayer setValue:layersCurrentAnimation forKey:@"basicAnimation"]
```

then if the animation was to stop I would get the animation value out from the layer and re-run it

```
CABasicAnimation *thisAnimation = [myAnimatedLayer  valueForKey:@"basicAnimation"];

[myAnimatedLayer addAnimation:thisAnimation forKey:nil];
```