# CALayer in a UIImageView

Tags: iphone, uiimageview, calayer, layer

I have a **CALayer** and I would like to use it as an **UIImageView**. That way I'll be able to move it with timers etc... so here  the layer :

```
CALayer *rootLayer  = [CALayer layer];
```

And I would like to move it with timer like that :

```
Image.center=CGPointMake(Image.center.x +10, Image.center.y );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this you'll need a `CABasicAnimation`. For the timer, create an `NSTimer`. Make sure that the timer fires the method on the main thread using one of the `performSelectorOnMainThread` methods.

That method will add the `CABasicAnimation` to the layer. You'll have to be careful with the end positions as when the animation finishes, your layer will still be visible in it's original position.

To resolve that you'll need to update the model value of the layer in the `animationDidStart` delegate callback of the `CABasicAnimation`.

Note that if it's a repeating animation - which I guess it is given you're using a timer - you can use the `removedOnCompletion` flag. That means you can re-use the same animation repeatedly. Check out this question for details on how to make use of that:

[How to reuse an CABasicAnimation when not removed after completion?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4758085/how-to-reuse-an-cabasicanimation-when-not-removed-after-completion)

Comment: so it's impossible to assign a layer to a uiimageview ?

Comment: The image view already has a layer. All views are backed by a CALayer. You access that property by calling myview.layer. When you have that just add the animation to that layer using addAnimation

Comment: final little question and I accept your answer: is it better for performance to use a layer for a uiimageView instead of a image.png ?

Comment: You will always be using a layer if you use a UIView or UiView subclass. The main performance consideration is to only load the image once. If you use the UIImage method imageNamed that will handle that for you. Does that make sense?

Comment: I can't do: image.layer=rootLayer. there is an error :request for member 'layer' in something not a structure or union

Comment: yeah you can't do that. Why do you want to change the image.layer to be a different layer? Why not just add the animation to image.layer?

Comment: doesn't work as in you don't see the animation? Try putting a break point into the delegate callbacks animationDidStop and animationDidStart. Don't forget to set the animation.delegate to receive the callbacks. There is a flag in animationDidStop that will tell you if the animation finished or not.